# Render Query results in a View using Twig in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I'm trying to display my query result into my View.
However, I can only render a part of that result.

My Repository with my Query :

```
public function findIdQuestion($id) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('question')
            ->andWhere('question.id_categorie = :id')
            ->leftjoin('App\Entity\Reponse','reponse','WITH','reponse.id_question = question.id')
            ->addSelect('reponse')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery();

        $results = $query->getResult();

        return $results;

  }
```

Here is my Controller :

```
public function play(Request $request) {

    $id = $request->query->get('id');

    $cat = $this->repository->findIdQuestion($id);

    dump($cat);

    return $this->render('quiz_select.html.twig', [
        'affichage' => $cat
    ]);
}
```

And my Twig View:

```
    {% block body %}
<h1>Questions</h1>
    {% for cate in affichage %}
        <p>{{ dump(cate) }}</p>
        <p>{{ cate.question }}</p>      
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

This works perfectly, but I need to display every 'reponse' too.

I've tried:

```
    {% for cate in affichage %}
        <p>{{ dump(cate) }}</p>
        <p>{{ cate.question }}</p>
            {% for reponse in cate.question %}
                <p>{{ reponse }}</p>
            {% endfor %}      
    {% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't show anything
I also tried :

```
    {% for cate in affichage %}
        <p>{{ dump(cate) }}</p>
        <p>{{ cate.question }}</p>
        <p>{{ cate.reponse }}</p>     
    {% endfor %}
```

But I get that error:

Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

This is what I have in my dump(cate) :

```
    App\Entity\Question {#563 ▼
  -id: 21
  +id_categorie: 3
  -question: "Que signifie le verbe Enrêner ?"
  -reponse: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#512 ▼
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: App\Entity\Question {#563}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#265 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "question"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#518 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#568 ▶}
    #initialized: false
  }
}
App\Entity\Reponse {#571 ▼
  -id: 31
  -id_question: 11
  -reponse: "Appellation d'Origine Contrôlée"
  -reponse_expected: 1
  -question: null
}
```

And these are my two Entities 
Question :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id_categorie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Reponse", mappedBy="question")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $reponse;

    public function setReponse(Reponse $reponse) {
        $this->reponse = $reponse;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getReponse () {
        return $this->reponse;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdCategorie(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_categorie;
    }

    public function setIdCategorie(int $id_categorie): self
    {
        $this->id_categorie = $id_categorie;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function setQuestion(string $question): self
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Reponse :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ReponseRepository")
 */
class Reponse
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id_question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $reponse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $reponse_expected;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="reponse",)
     */

    private $question;

    public function setQuestion(Question $question) {
        $this->question = $question;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuestion () {
        return $this->question;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdQuestion(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id_question;
    }

    public function setIdQuestion(int $id_question): self
    {
        $this->id_question = $id_question;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReponse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->reponse;
    }

    public function setReponse(string $reponse): self
    {
        $this->reponse = $reponse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReponseExpected(): ?int
    {
        return $this->reponse_expected;
    }

    public function setReponseExpected(?int $reponse_expected): self
    {
        $this->reponse_expected = $reponse_expected;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close.

First, you are manually joining the reponse entity instead of using your association. This is messing up the format of results. Update your repository to join using the `OneToMany` association defined on the entity like this:

```php
public function findIdQuestion($id) {
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('question')
            ->andWhere('question.id_categorie = :id')
            ->leftjoin('question.reponse','reponse')
            ->addSelect('reponse')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery();

        $results = $query->getResult();

        return $results;

  }
```

Second, You need to loop `cate.reponse` instead of `cate.question`

```
    {% for cate in affichage %}
        <p>{{ dump(cate) }}</p>
        <p>{{ cate.question}}</p>
            {% for reponse in cate.reponse %}
                <p>{{ reponse.reponse }}</p>
            {% endfor %}      
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show the 'reponse', only the question. But I don't get any errors

Comment: What fields do you want to show from the `reponse`? In the `for reponse in cate.reponse`  loop, `reponse` is an object, so `<p>{{ reponse }}</p>` probably isn't what you want there. You need to do something like `<p>{{ reponse.reponse }}<ps>`

Comment: I want to show the 'reponse' in my App\Entity\Reponse, it is shown in my dump(cate) but I don't know how to show it in my Twig, `{{ reponse.reponse }}` gives me the same result

Comment: `{{ reponse.reponse }}` should work. I think I just noticed something else wrong. You aren't joining your association correctly in the repo method. Hang on, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I used your answer but same result, the questions are here but no sign of the 'reponse'.The dump also doesn't show the 'reponse' anymore

Comment: It sounds like the association is not getting populated for some reason. I'm guessing your mappings have a problem, or there is an issue with the data in the database.

Comment: In your controller where you have `dump($cat);`, do `foreach ($cat->getReponse() as $reponse) { dump($reponse); }` and see if the reponses show up then

Comment: Ah, your mappings definitely have a problem. In the dump for `App\Entity\Reponse`, notice the `question` field is `null`. It should be the `Question` entity associated with the `Reponse` if the mappings were correct.

Comment: I get that error `Call to a member function getReponse() on array`

Comment: Yes, you need to loop `$cat` first. It's hard to write out code in these comments, but something like this: `foreach ($cat as $c) { foreach ($c->getReponse() as $reponse) { dump($reponse); }}` If you don't see any dumps from this, it means your association is not getting populated in the query, which would mean your mappings are wrong.

Comment: I don't see any results so it should be my mapping. Thanks !